# JAXB - Unmarshalling custom xml throws javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to *unmarshal a custom xml to java object* throws the following exception.

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://test.neps.com/jrx", local:"uirx"). Expected elements are <{http://test.neps.com/jrx}person>

**The xml,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jrx:uirx xmlns:jrx="http://test.neps.com/jrx">
  <jrx:person>
    <jrx:ulement name="id" type="Integer" value=""/>
    <jrx:ulement name="name" type="String" value=""/>
    </jrx:person>
    </jrx:uirx>
```

**The java object,**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person", namespace = "http://test.neps.com/jrx")
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Please do suggest some fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your root element (the top level element) is `<jrx:uirx>` and not `<jrs:person>`.  You need to create something to map to that top level element.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "uirx", namespace = "http://test.neps.com/jrx")
public class Uirx {

    private Person person;

    @XmlElement
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```